# Is it possible to edit properties in a MsBuildWorkspace (roslyn)?

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

I would like to add a couple of properties in the MsBuildWorkspace and I have tried this:

```
        using (var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["CopyBuildOutputToOutputDirectory"] = "true",
            ["SkipCopyBuildProduct"] = "false",
            ["DesignTimeBuild"] = "false",
            ["BuildProjectReferences"] = "true",
            ["AutoGenerateBindingRedirects"] = "false",
            ["UseCommonOutputDirectory"] = "false",
            ["SkipCompilerExecution"] = "false"
        }))
        {
            var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
            return solution;
        }
```

But this only give me:

```
An element with the same key but a different value already exists.
```

I tried to look at the workspace object after creation and it is a ImmutableDictionary. So I guess they don't want us to change specific properties or something I'm missing?

Edit with stacktrace:

```
at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.HashBucket.Add(TKey key, TValue value, IEqualityComparer`1 keyOnlyComparer, IEqualityComparer`1 valueComparer, KeyCollisionBehavior behavior, OperationResult& result)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items, MutationInput origin, KeyCollisionBehavior collisionBehavior)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs, Boolean avoidToHashMap)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 pairs)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.Build.ProjectBuildManager.StartBatchBuild(IDictionary`2 globalProperties)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectLoader.Worker.<LoadAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectLoader.<LoadSolutionInfoAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<OpenSolutionAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Comment: Can you post the callstack for the exception you are getting? Is is coming form [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/8d71c3afb35f9b8ca2a648ec378599ad9c1c099a/src/Workspaces/Core/MSBuild/MSBuild/Build/ProjectBuildManager.cs#L79)?

Comment: I edit the question with stacktrace. It seems to come close to where you point it out. @JonathonMarolf

Comment: I would file an issues on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new I do not believe we support over-writing already defined properties